# Rewrite rules in ANTLR

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr

I am doing an ANTLR specification. In my AST i need to do this one:

```
characters ('*'^|'+'^|'?'^)?
```

I need to do a rewrite rule that will present in ast instead of * ASTERISK, instead of + PLUS and instead of ? QMARK nodes?

I know that if we would have something like this:

```
characters '*'
```

it can be rewrited as

```
^(ASTERISK characters)
```

but i dont know how to deal with | operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
grammar T;

// options ...

tokens {
  ASTERISK;
  PLUS;
  QMARK;
}

// @header and/or @members ...

rule
 : (characters -> characters) ( '*' -> ^(ASTERISK characters)
                              | '+' -> ^(PLUS characters)
                              | '?' -> ^(QMARK characters)
                              )?
 ;
```

The key here is that if the optional `*`, `+` or `?` are *not* present, the `characters` will just stay `characters` by the rewrite rule: `(characters -> characters)`.